# How to FastCopy Only...? Junctions? Hard Links? etc?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, clone, junction

I'm new to FastCopy.  How can I use it to copy only a certain type of file/folder?  e.g. How to copy only junctions, and nothing else?